# Type a paragraph onto a word document from data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an excel document that I use to create emails from 17 different templates. In the excel workbook, I can select which template I need to use and input data to fill in variable information in the template.

I created this macro which will type out the data onto a word document into the exact format needed for each template. All of this is done in the background and the contents of the document are copied to my clipboard. The word document is also closed automatically as it is no longer needed.

The macro I created works, but it is a little slow and I would like assistance with making it work faster.

Here is the macro I created. Any tips to improve the efficiency would be greatly appreciated!

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub TypeRangeToWord_Single()

    'Declare my word Variables
    Dim WrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim WrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Values to Type")
    
    'Create a new instance of word.
    Set WrdApp = New Word.Application
    Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Add
    
    'Type the values in Word
    With WrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection
            .Font.Name = "Calibri (Body)"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .TypeText sh.Range("A1")
            .Font.Bold = False
            .TypeText sh.Range("A2")
            .TypeText sh.Range("A3")
            .TypeText sh.Range("A4")
            .TypeText sh.Range("A5")
            .TypeText sh.Range("A6")
            .TypeText sh.Range("A7")
            .TypeText sh.Range("A8") & Chr(11) & Chr(11)
            .Font.Underline = True
            .TypeText sh.Range("A9")
            .TypeText sh.Range("A10") & Chr(11) & Chr(11)
            .Font.Underline = False
            .TypeText sh.Range("A11")
            .TypeText sh.Range("A12") & Chr(11) & Chr(11)
            .TypeText sh.Range("A13")
            .TypeText sh.Range("A14")
            .Font.Bold = True
            .TypeText sh.Range("A15")
            .Font.Bold = False
            .Font.Underline = True
            .TypeText sh.Range("A16")
            .Font.Underline = False
            .TypeText sh.Range("A17")
            .Font.Underline = True
            .TypeText sh.Range("A18")
            .Font.Underline = False
            .TypeText sh.Range("A19")
            .Font.Underline = True
            .TypeText sh.Range("A20")
            .Font.Underline = False
            .TypeText sh.Range("A21")
            .Font.Underline = True
            .TypeText sh.Range("A22")
            .Font.Underline = False
            .TypeText sh.Range("A23") & Chr(11) & Chr(11)
            .TypeText sh.Range("A24")
            .Font.Bold = True
            .TypeText sh.Range("A25") & " "
            .TypeText sh.Range("A26") & " "
            .TypeText sh.Range("A27")
            .Font.Bold = False
            .TypeText sh.Range("A28")
            .TypeText sh.Range("A29") & Chr(11) & Chr(11)
            .TypeText sh.Range("A30") & Chr(11)
            .TypeText sh.Range("A31")
            
    End With
    
'copy values and close word doc
WrdDoc.Range.Copy
WrdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

'message box
MsgBox "Notice copied to clipboard!"

End Sub
```